# SQL - How to add dummy blank data in query for every data variations?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got this SQL table which I plan to use in an SQL query:

```
| Code_1 | Name_1 | Code_2 | Name_2 | Code_3 | Name_3 | Code_4 | Name_4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  A01   | Alice  |  B01   | Bernie |  C01   | Charle |  D01   | Dean   |
|  A01   | Alice  |  B01   | Bernie |  C01   | Charle |  D02   | Donny  |
|  A01   | Alice  |  B01   | Bernie |  C02   | Claire |  E01   | Ellie  |

'and so on
```

In my query I want to:

1. Merge Code and Name together into a string.
2. Display Code and the merged Code + Name string.
3. Add a dummy row where `Code_4` and `Name_4` is blank.

Like so:

```
| Code_1 |    Name_1    | Code_2 |    Name_2    | Code_3 |    Name_3    | Code_4 |    Name_4    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  A01   | A01 - Alice  |  B01   | B01 - Bernie |  C01   | C01 - Charle |        |              |
|  A01   | A01 - Alice  |  B01   | B01 - Bernie |  C01   | C01 - Charle |  D01   | D01 - Dean   |
|  A01   | A01 - Alice  |  B01   | B01 - Bernie |  C01   | C01 - Charle |  D02   | D02 - Donny  |
|  A01   | A01 - Alice  |  B01   | B01 - Bernie |  C02   | C02 - Claire |        |              |
|  A01   | A01 - Alice  |  B01   | B01 - Bernie |  C02   | C02 - Claire |  E01   | E01 - Ellie  |

'and so on
```

The query I have so far:

```
select distinct [Code_1], [Code_1] + ' - ' + [Name_1] as [Name_1],
                [Code_2], [Code_2] + ' - ' + [Name_2] as [Name_2],
                [Code_3], [Code_3] + ' - ' + [Name_3] as [Name_3],
                [Code_4], [Code_4] + ' - ' + [Name_4] as [Name_4] from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[NAMES]
```

I still can't figure out how to put the blank dummy row for `Code_4` & `Name_4`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select [Code_1], [Code_1] + ' - ' + [Name_1] as [Name_1],
       [Code_2], [Code_2] + ' - ' + [Name_2] as [Name_2],
       [Code_3], [Code_3] + ' - ' + [Name_3] as [Name_3],
       [Code_4], [Code_4] + ' - ' + [Name_4] as [Name_4]
from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[NAMES]
union all
select distinct [Code_1], [Code_1] + ' - ' + [Name_1] as [Name_1],
       [Code_2], [Code_2] + ' - ' + [Name_2] as [Name_2],
       [Code_3], [Code_3] + ' - ' + [Name_3] as [Name_3],
       NULL as [Code_4], NULL as [Name_4]
```

Based on your sample data, you do not need `select distinct` for the overall data, only for the part with null'ed out columns.